# Get monthly distribution of data within single SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a monthly distribution of my data by using one single mysql statement. Expected result of the statement below: A table with 12 rows. If in one month no data is available it should return 0 for this month. However in the result of the current SQL Statement one or more rows are missing if data is missing. What I am Missing?

```sql
SELECT m.Month as m1, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(crdate)) as m2,
SUM(CASE WHEN keylock = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1, SUM(CASE WHEN keylock = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c2
FROM tx_bhm_domain_model_access a 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 2 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 3 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 4 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 5 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 6 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 7 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 8 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 9 AS Month
    UNION SELECT 10 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 11 AS Month 
    UNION SELECT 12 AS Month ) m
ON MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.crdate)) = m.Month
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.crdate))=2018 
GROUP BY m.Month
ORDER BY m.Month
```

Comment: For things you're missing, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `YEAR()` comparison needs to go in the `ON` clause.  I much prefer `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT m.Month as m1, MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(crdate)) as m2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN keylock = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN keylock = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c2
FROM (SELECT 1 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS Month UNION ALL 
      SELECT 3 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 AS Month UNION ALL 
      SELECT 5 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 8 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 9 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 10 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 11 AS Month UNION ALL
      SELECT 12 AS Month
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     tx_bhm_domain_model_access a
     ON MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.crdate)) = m.Month AND
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.crdate)) = 2018 
GROUP BY m.Month
ORDER BY m.Month;
```

I also changed the `UNION`s to `UNION ALL`s.  There is no need to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: You save my day!